# Search using comma separated string

Tags: php, mysql

So I think I completely misunderstood how FIND_IN_SET work

```
SELECT
    u.*, p.*
FROM
    users u
INNER JOIN profiles p ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE
FIND_IN_SET('1,4,7', p.fruits)
```

This is not working as I thought it would.

1,4,7 represent the fruits selected by the user to search

p.fruits can look something like this 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 5,6,7 or 1,6,7 etc

Basically I want to find the records if any of the values in the first argument match any of the values in the second argument.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you constructing this query dynamically in PHP?  You're probably going to have to build a chain like `FIND_IN_SET(1, p.fruits) OR FIND_IN_SET(4, p.fruits)...`  This is one of the many reasons comma-separated values in a single column are not a good idea.

Comment: If you split them up you could use LIKE: WHERE fruits LIKE '%1%' OR fruits LIKE '%2%' etc.

Comment: @RyanS then you need to account for the surrounding commas, and the beginning & end of the string not having them for _each_ desired value.  `FIND_IN_SET()` is the right solution, but the data should be normalized to begin with.

Comment: I'm only using commas because I don't know of any other way. Any suggestions. Originally I had a column for each fruit, but then decided to store all of the values in a single column as the amount of checkboxes grew.

Comment: How are the fruits defined in the table? is it a set? if so, michael's solution is great

Comment: @user1019144 They should be normalized out into another table which links whatever `p` stores to multiple fruits in a one-to-many relationship.  Its columns would be `p_id, fruit_id`. If you post the table structures for `profiles` and `fruits` (assuming you have a `fruits` table), we could be more specific about how the join table would look.

Comment: I am storing the fruit values in a config array

Comment: I am inquiring about the p.fruits column in db. Is it a varchar or set or text ?

Comment: Consider creating a table to hold the `fruits`, so your data isn't mixed between PHP code and the database. That would also enable you to be able to query and act on it entirely outside of PHP.

Comment: Yeh well, originally I had a table for fruit preferences related to each user, basically a tinyint for each fruit checkbox. I just wasn't sure if this was the most efficient way, since fruits was just one of many categories of preferences

Comment: If you are going to make a search on them like you are doing above, they should be atomic (every columnmust have one value and one value only) (sets and enums are special and exceptions because you can query them with mysql commands natuarally)

Comment: _“So I think I completely misunderstood how FIND_IN_SET work”_ – to me it rather looks like you were not even able to detect the right order of parameters from the manual …

Answer (score 0):

if your p.fruits column is a varchar (which is not ideal for this situation, but if it is so) your query will be like

```
where …  ( concat(',', p.fruits , ‘,’) like ‘%,1,%’  
or concat(',', p.fruits , ‘,’) like ‘%,4,%’  or concat(',',p.fruits , ‘,’) like ‘%,7,%’ ) ...
```

this won't be good for indexes since concatenation will disable usage of indexes .. 
better solution would be turn the column into a set and do the query like Michael's above .. 
or you can create a new table called user_fruits(fk_user_id int, fruit_id int) and  create unique index on both fields and do the search in user_fruits table

Comment: Careful though.  That would also match `111`, `14`, and `97`, none of which is in the input set.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FIELD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) instead of that.

```
FIELD(p.fruits, 1,4,7)
```

You should refer to this article:

[10 things in MySQL (that won’t work as expected)](http://explainextended.com/2010/11/03/10-things-in-mysql-that-wont-work-as-expected/)